# How to add the Numbers from the User into a List

Tags: python, list, median

I have been trying to write a Mean, Median, and Mode Calculator. I have two questions. 1) How would I add the numbers the user inputs into the empty list. If I simply punch in the numbers it gives me this error:

```
userNumbers = int(raw_input("Enter the digits here: "))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2, 4, 6, 8'
```

I would love to know how to avoid that.
Secondly, I am using Python 2.7.10 and will be moving to 3.4 soon. I know that on 3.4 there is a module named statistics with a median function, however it doesn't work on 2.7.10. Out of curiosity, how would I find the median without the function. Thanks everyone!

```
from collections import Counter


def numberPlacement():
    print("Welcome to the PyCalculator, please enter a series of digits!")
    userNumbers = int(raw_input("Enter the digits here: "))
    userNumbers = []


def userChoice():
    while True:
        print("Awesome, now that we haave your numbers please choose an operation (Mean, Median, or Mode!)")
        userAnswer = raw_input("Enter your choice here: ")
        if userAnswer == "Mean":
            mean = sum(userNumbers) / float(len(userNumbers))
            return mean
        elif userAnswer == "Mode":
            mode = Counter(userNumbers)
            return mode
        continue

print numberPlacement()
print userChoice()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are receiving is because you are trying to cast invalid characters to int.

Your input is: `1, 2, 3, 4` so those commas is what is causing that error.

To rectify this, simply remove the int() cast you have, make your input a list by appending a `.split(',')` to your input. What that split does is convert your string to a list by splitting on the comma. That way you will have a list of numbers represented by strings.

So, since you are doing math, you need to make sure you are actually using the numerical representation and not the string representation of the data in your list. There is a neat one line solution for this you can do, by using Python's `map` method ([documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map)), that will cast all your entries to an int.

So, your user input, can simply look like this:

Python 3:

```
userNumbers = list(map(int, input("Enter the digits here: ").split(',')))
```

Python 2:

```
userNumbers = map(int, raw_input("Enter the digits here: ").split(','))
```

There is another problem in your code. In your userChoice method, you are referencing `userNumbers`. Which I think is the reference to `userNumbers` inside the `numberPlacement` method. You can't do this.

What I suggest doing, since it seems like you want to call these two methods separately, is make your userChoice method take a parameter, which would be a list, called userNumber. So simply:

```
def userChoice(userNumbers):
    # the rest of your code
```

Now, it is very important to remember, that this `userNumbers` in your `userChoice` method is not the same as the `userNumbers` in your `numberPlacement` method. To understand why, this is part of scoping. Which you can read about [here](http://def%20userChoice():).

So, then when you call your methods now, you just have to do something like this:

```
number_placements = numberPlacement()
print(number_placements)
print(userChoice(number_placements))
```

When you put it all together, your code now looks like this:

(Python 2)

```
from collections import Counter


def numberPlacement():
    print("Welcome to the PyCalculator, please enter a series of digits!")
    userNumbers = map(int, raw_input("Enter the digits here: ").split(','))
    return userNumbers


def userChoice(userNumbers):
    while True:
        print("Awesome, now that we haave your numbers please choose an operation (Mean, Median, or Mode!)")
        userAnswer = raw_input("Enter your choice here: ")
        if userAnswer == "Mean":
            mean = sum(userNumbers) / float(len(userNumbers))
            return mean
        elif userAnswer == "Mode":
            mode = Counter(userNumbers)
            return mode
        continue


r = numberPlacement()
print(userChoice(r))
```

Demo:

```
Welcome to the PyCalculator, please enter a series of digits!
Enter the digits here: 1,2,3,4
Awesome, now that we haave your numbers please choose an operation (Mean, Median, or Mode!)
Enter your choice here: Mode
Counter({1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1})
```

Comment: @Jack You are welcome. Let me know if it works out for you.

Comment: Sadly, I tested the code and it gave me back the same error.

Comment: @Jack It works for me. I took your code and just replaced the line I put in my answer. Look here: http://pastebin.com/VGb9zhwD

Comment: May I ask what version you are running because I am running 2.7.10 and it gives me this error: AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'split' Thanks so much!

Comment: I'm glad you brought that up. I know why. Updating.

Comment: There is another problem I found in your code. I'm updating my answer.

Comment: @Jack I found a few things. Take a look. I'm pretty sure this works.

Comment: Thank you so much for the updated code. I have one final question, I hope you don't mind, but when I run the program and after I enter my digits and choose, say Mode, it calls it undefined. What was wrong?

Comment: I just copy pasted the code I put in my answer, and ran it in Python 2, and it worked. I updated my answer with a "Demo", to show what I got. I really don't know what that means without seeing your code, sorry.

Comment: Ah it works if I add the quotations around Mode, I really don't know haha. Thanks for everything!

Answer (score 1):

You need to split your input:

```
a = raw_input("Enter the digits here: ").split(',')
b = [int(x) for x in a]
```

Then you can reference your numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You're printing random things that don't need printing, and you've also got locally scoped variables you're trying to call globally

```
def numberPlacement():
    print("Welcome to the PyCalculator, please enter a series of digits, comma seperated!")
    userNumbers = raw_input("Enter the digits here: ")
    return [ int(u.strip()) for u in userNumbers.split(',') ]


def userChoice(userNumbers):
    print("Awesome, now that we haave your numbers please choose an operation (Mean, Median, or Mode!)")
    userAnswer = raw_input("Enter your choice here: ")

    if userAnswer == "Mean":

        mean = sum(userNumbers) / float(len(userNumbers))
        return mean

    #omitted

userNumbers = numberPlacement()
print(userChoice(userNumbers))



#list comprehension rewritten as a basic for loop in response to question in comment

final_list = []
for u in userNumbers.split(','):
    x = u.strip()
    y = int(x)
    final_list.append(y)

return final_list
```

Comment: One more question, on the 4th line, could you explain what you did? I have only been coding for about a week now so I am still new to this! Thanks!

Comment: That's called a list comprehension, a google is a much better teacher than i as to all the ins and outs.  They can be used for a lot of different things depending on how you build them.  In this example, its basically a for loop.  Try reading it as "split the string usernumbers on commas, and for each element in the resulting list, strip off leading/trailing whitespace, convert it to an integer.  return a list of of all the final results."  You could write it as a for loop if you wanted to.

Comment: added an example of how to do it as a for loop to make it more understandable for you.

Comment: Ah, that makes a little more sense, thanks. I'll just have to read up on it a little more. I hope this coding thing gets a little easier. Thank you!

Comment: Also, the statistics module is available for python 2.x, its just not part of the base install.  in your venv, or as root/administrator, use pip to install statistics